# How to assign an array to a jagged array column without declaring the former as Variant in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, jagged-arrays

To put simply, I have a jagged array with multiple arrays inside and I want to assign a new array with the values of one of the arrays in the jagged array. Something like this:

```
arr1 = jaggedarr(2)
```

The above gives the array arr1 the values of the 2nd array in the jagged array. I can do this by declaring arr1 as a Variant, but am wondering is there a way to do it by declaring it as, say, a Double without Looping.

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `arr1` as a Double array:

> ```
> Dim arr1() As Double
> ```

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim arr1() As Double
    Dim values(1 To 10) As Double
    Dim jaggedarr(2)
    jaggedarr(2) = values
    arr1 = jaggedarr(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi TinMan... sorry.. I forgot to mention that the arrays in jaggedarr are declared as Variants due to my data import function that generated the jagged array. So your method gives me a mismatch. Actually... thinking about it, i think the fact that I can't change the declaration of the arrays in jaggedarr to be anything but Variant, my problem is probably not solvable by construct. Sorry if I wasted your effort.